# Discord.py new member role code not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to add a role to members that have just joined; however, my code seems to not react at all. I get 0 responses on both Discord and console.

The bot's role is on the top of the role list.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  join_guild = await client.fetch_guild(id_here)
  role = join_guild.get_role(id_here)


  await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Have you enabled intents?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `fetch_guild()` you already have your [`discord.Member`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) object from the [`on_member_join`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join) event

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = member.guild.get_role(...)  # role id
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

The reason you're not getting any response is because `on_member_join` requires [`Intents.members`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.Intents.members) to be enabled, here is an example

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True  # Subscribe to the privileged members intent.
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

Learn more about [`Intents`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/intents.html?highlight=intents)

Comment: It would be better if this were marked as a duplicate instead of answered, as it gets asked almost every day.